# What should I replace a4j:htmlCommandLink to in RichFaces 4.0?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm using JSF 2.1_29 and after upgrading RichFaces 3.3.3 up to 4.5.2.Final I've got a problem with `a4j:htmlCommandLink` tag. It's just not defined in the RichFaces tag library. I got the following expception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: bonusList.jspx @257,109 <a4j:htmlCommandLink> Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/a4j, but no tag was defined for name: htmlCommandLink
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
            org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
```

BTW, I've read the RichFaces `a4j`-components [migration guide](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-ComponentsMigration-A4jComponents) and it doesn't says anything about replcaing that component in RichFaces 4.x.x. So, what should I replace that component to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `a4j:commandLink`. See [RichFaces documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/).

Other alternatives: `h:commandLink`, `h:outputLink` and `h:link`. See [JSF documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/).